# Power machine off after failed login attempts from physical access

Tags: linux, security, disk-encryption, fail2ban

I would like to know if there are any common techniques of powering your computer off after a number of failed login attempts from the machine locally (from the terminal login, or from lightdm for example).

For SSH or any remote login, I would just use fail2ban.  I'm asking this for the purposes of a personal computer, like desktop or laptop which is more likely to be stolen.

The reason I want the machine to power off during local brute force attempts is to force the thief out of the encrypted disk which had been unlocked during this bootup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related to PAM, You would want to research how to implement pam_exec.so to run a script to power off the machine for failed login attempts during authentication.

There's a good resource here where someone implemented the same type of setup where he kept track of login counts to determine when the shutdown script should be called.

Source: https://cowboyprogrammer.org/2016/09/reboot_machine_on_wrong_password/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with `logwatcher` or `swatch` and shutdown after X failed login attempts. Local bruteforce? -- You mean somebody has a FPGA physically attached to your server attempting brute force?

Answer (score 0):

***First, to be safe**, open another tty (Alt+Ctrl+F3) and login, so if you mess with your system you can revert your changes. (If you don't do that, you can still recover your system by: 1. At boot, edit grub boot line (press e) and add `init=/bin/sh` to the line starting by "linux", and when you reach the console: 2. `mount -o remount,rw /`

**Create your script**
`sudo vi /opt/loginfail`

With a content like this:

> #!/bin/dash
>
> workdir="/home/USER/Downloads/failedlogin.d/"
> failfile="$workdir/failfile"
>
> [ ! -d "$workdir" ] && mkdir "$workdir"
> [ ! -f "$failfile" ] && echo "0" > "$failfile"
>
> trial="$(cat "$failfile")"
> trials="$((trial + 1))"
> echo "$trials" > "$failfile"
>
> if [ "$trials" -gt "2" ]; then
> echo "0" > "$failfile"
> sudo /sbin/poweroff --no-wall --poweroff
> fi

**Make it executable**
`sudo chmod +x /opt/loginfail`

**Edit /etc/pam.d/common-auth**
and change the line

> auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure

to

> auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure

and add the line:

> auth    [default=ignore]                pam_exec.so seteuid
> /opt/loginfail